# Can non jews give death penalty for something other then the 7 laws of noah

Tags: halacha, death, noachide-laws

Can non jews give death penalty for something other then the 7 laws of noah?
Source and clarification (in what cases) please

Comment: What the penalty is to a Noahide for violation of one of the 7 Noahide commandments does not exclude whatever system of laws the non-Jewish government establishes. They are two completely different things. And if any given non-Jewish government establishes a particular law whose violation results in a penalty of death, they would be completely within their rights.

Comment: @YaacovDeane sources please, (so death penelty for hachnosas orchim is ok?)

Comment: @hazoriz Are you really questioning whether non-Jews have a right to have a system of law/jurisprudence in their own country? The 7 Noahide laws are only those laws from the Creator that are incumbent upon all mankind. But any nation can have laws in addition to those. The same principle applies to Jews. If Jews establish a (secular) state, they can, by agreement, make whatever legal system they want for that domain. It doesn't alter or eliminate their obligation, as Jews, to keep the Torah. It is in addition to it. That is what is actually happening today in the state of Israel.

Comment: @YaacovDeane i am ok with system of law, but if it is against the 7 it might be not allowed , (for example if they kil (or kidnap steal (by putting in prisen) l for hachnosas orchim, i guess they can not legalize gay relations

Comment: That’s the point. But regarding your particular example, hachnosat orchim, they could make the practice illegal and with a penalty of death for anyone convicted of the violation. If their courts (an obligation for Noahides) found someone guilty, they could sentence the violator to death, even a Jew. It wouldn’t be any kind a problem.

Comment: @YaacovDeane source please (according to rambam the court obligation is that it kill the violators of the other 6 laws, how do you know that it gives them the right to kill for achnossas orhim (if they desyed to )?)

Comment: The obligation upon Noahides is that they should not fail to establish courts of Justice. But the function of those courts is not limited to adjudication of the 7 laws of Noach. And this doesn’t even address the idea that outside of the land of Israel, there is no consequence from a Jewish court if the non-Jew doesn’t take on the 7 commandments except from G-d. The laws from Rambam in Hilchot Melachim are aimed at how a Jewish court inside the land of Israel would adjudicate cases dealing with Noahides.

Comment: @YaacovDeane source please

Comment: Try reading Rambam’s introduction to the Mishnah Torah. It’s not the laws for Noahides or non-Jews. It’s all for Jews, including his discussion of the 7 laws of Noah.

Comment: To quote Rambam’s introduction, “To summarize: (The intent of this text is) that a person will not need another text at all with regard to any Jewish law...”. It is not the laws of the Noahides.

Comment: @YaacovDeane ok, but how can i trust you, i need a source that you are right ,